# Substring_Index to Date

Tags: mysql

I have problem,, so i have table let said name is table1, that table1 have filed name UserName. And the value like this "**Jiyo-192.168.10.22 Date 31-Aug-2016 Jam 11:35:36**", so the format value like this
**&Name&-&ipaddress& Date &datetime&**. Cause i wanna UserName became date i use subtring_index like this
**SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(UserName,'Date ',-1),' Jam',1) AS date1**
But my problem is i need query where date1 between two date, i just use my code like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(UserName,'Date ',-1),' Jam',1) FROM table1 
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(UserName,'Date ',-1),' Jam',1) BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2016-11-01','%d-%b-%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT('2016-11-18','%d-%b-%Y')
```

But is not wokring the result showing from 12-Mar-2007 until 17-Nov-2016. Did i get something wrong or substring_index really not working to get value date??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `CAST()` to perform a `BETWEEN` like that:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(UserName,'Date ',-1),' Jam',1) FROM table1 
  WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(UserName,'Date ',-1),' Jam',1)
    BETWEEN CAST('2016-11-01' AS DATETIME)
      AND CAST('2016-11-18' AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: isn't not working, i have data on 17 November 2016, when i use CAST() there's no result.